# How to memoize a lambda function in Jetpack Compose like useCallback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a memoized callback function in Jetpack Compose, similar to React's [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

For example I'd like to use this to create a `submit` lambda function that contains the logic for submitting a form, but I don't want this lambda to be recreated on each recomposition. This should only be recreated when its dependencies change.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lambda memoization is done automatically by the compiler by generating a `remember` call implicitly based on the stable values captured by the lambda. You only need `remember` explicitly if one or more of the captured values is not considered stable by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. Is this behaviour documented anywhere? I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: you can print (logcat) hashcode of lambdas created inside composable and you will notice that it's different on each Recomposition , but if you put it in `remember { { .. } }` then it will the same hashcode. So this answer is not true

Comment: my statement above is true if lambda contains some code, I tried with empty body and then only in that case the hashcode will be the same without `remember`, so basically in practice they won't never be remembered automatically if you have have some code lines there

Comment: the references I used in lambdas were always of the same instance (same hashcode) on each recomposition, so it seems, we need to `remember` for all references used in lambda anyway when creating a lambda: `remember(ref1,...) {  { /* lambda which uses ref1, .... */ }}`

Comment: I remembered most lambdas and composable top screen function performance increased (it executes faster)

Answer (score 1):

The normal `remember`/`rememberSaveable` functions can be used for this. This will only recreate the lambda function when the given dependencies change.

```
val submit = rememberSaveable(dependency1, dependency2) {
    {
        // Logic here
    }
}

submit()
```

Comment: you should not use `rememberSaveable` for lambdas

Comment: @user924 It would be helpful if you could clarify why it should not be used

Comment: why do you need to save lambdas in bundle ? just use `remember`, that's enough, it's not parceable anyway